# native web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, app-store, native

In one of my projects, the client wants to have an installable app ( native ) but this app will show just a web content in a WebKit ( the web page is built with iWebKit ).
My question is this: Will apple accept this app because the content can be changed, and should it be a web app, not a native one?

Answer (score 1):

If this just opens a website, then no apple will probably not accept it.

If the app is build using javascript and HTML which is bundelt with the app then yes, this is what tools like PhoneGap use.

Comment: thank you for replaying, in fact the app will show a web page with a list of items " RSS feed " we can choose one, then an other WEB page is opened.( i do this in native way with tableview .. but the client want it to be with iWebKit to can change ,i think, interface and functionality as he want) so ill tell him that its not a good idea ,thank you again .

Answer (score 0):

I believe they should(you never know with apple...), [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) is using a similar approach, and if you go [here](http://phonegap.com/apps/?d=iPhone), you will see quite a few apps made for iphone.

Comment: ok i see, but the problem is that the app is really small ( 2 web pages ) so ill try to convince the client to use the native one, if he wont then ill use the other on ,thank you very much .